# Div inside div including background image

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I've got two divs. First one is 'parent', which provides width and height for another div. Second div has background-attachment: fixed and there's a problem... My image won't display when width: 100% and height: 100%. When image has height: 800px, everything is fine, but first div won't scale with image when I change screen resolution so there's an empty space between image and rest of the content. Any ideas how to fix it ? Thanks for your response!

```
<div class="divimgparent">
<div class="divimg"></div>
</div>
.divimgparent {width: 100%; height: auto;}
.divimg {background: url("../images/1.jpg"); width: 100%; height: 800px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-attachment: fixed;}
```

Comment: Yes that is because you need to give `height` to either parent or child. `height:auto;` works based on content you have. It does not have specific height, where in your case 100%, it considers the 100% of `.divparentimg`

Comment: change background-size css property to cover. `background-size:cover;` Then image will be stretched according to screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Here your parent div not getting the height when your css is height: auto;. So, you need to define a height for your parent div.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.divimgparent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.divimg {background: url("http://www.ecdevelopment.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/hippie-flower.jpg");width: 100%; height: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-attachment: fixed;}
```

```html
<div class="divimgparent">
<div class="divimg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="divimgparent">
    <div class="divimg"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.divimgparent {width: 100%; height: 90vh;}
.divimg {background: url("http://s9.postimg.org/bxayc3y3z/Desert.jpg"); width: 100%; height:100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain; background-attachment: fixed;}
```

please try this.

demo